# Regex no funciona en produccion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, aplicación-web

Tengo un formulario para registrar correos, uso react y para validar ocupo un regex:

```
if( !emailRegex.test(user.email) ) {
  setErr({ ...err, emailErr: true });
  return
} else {
  setErr({ ...err, emailErr: false });
}
```

En dev funciona bien, valida correctamente pero en produccion todos los correos son incorrectos, claro no entra el else, alguien le ha pasado esto??

Comment: Intenta debugueando como llega `user.email` Puede que este llegando con caracteres extraños?

Comment: Por favor comparte el regex, te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [example]

Comment: Gracias, ya lo resolví.

Answer (score 1):

Vi que ya resolviste tu problema, pero dado que entiendo que puede que tengas muchas de estas validaciones con otros campos, un sencillo consejo para que tu código quede mas limpio:

```
const emailErr = !emailRegex.test(user.email);
setErr({ ...err,  emailErr })
```